# Hadoop vs Hazelcast

Tags: hadoop, hazelcast

What are the differences between hazelcast and hadoop Other than hazelcast is in memory and hadoop store data on disk.

1. What are the  distinct use cases for hadoop and hazelcast?
2. Hazelcast also support mapreduce freamework so the hazelcast is best alternative to hadoop?

Answer (score 5):

Hazelcast is a good alternative if you have a fair amount of data that you can hold in memory. You can also use a MapStore to write data to a backend database (like hadoop) so it will be used as some kind of a accelerator of the underlying backend storage.

So Hazelcast is best fit if your dataset you want to map fits into memory, hadoop is best fit if you have a huge amount of data and this won't fit into RAM. Otherways they should be pretty comparable in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask about use-cases. Tell us what you want to do. Just run Map/Reduce jobs? How many? What they do? And so on. Most of the time I heard about Hadoop was when some "IT organization" wanted to "develop a BigData capability".

Hazelcast has map/reduce. If anything I'd say it's closer to runtime (OLTP), then OLAP. BigData is not about runtime calculations/queries anyway, so the difference between disk and in-memory doesn't really matter.

Hadoop is used for many things: from complex parallel calculations to data warehousing through Hive. It also has many components beside Map/Reduce.

Most people use Hazelcast as a cache. I tried to use it as a database.